# I want to build a simple .Net service that runs on a server and simply hits a web address

Tags: windows-services

Can someone point me in the right direction here?  Suprisingly, I cannot find any info via Google searches (Probably because I don't know what to search for).

Anyway, I have built a site that does some API calls and saves some data to a database.  This was done manually, but now would like to be able to just have the server make this call once a night.

However, I don't even know where to begin to get info on the subject.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, the windows service is a good option for such a case.

Start first by testing the API using an ASP.NET site as a client to consume this API. If you have done so, start looking for `WebRequest` and `HttpWebRequest` (both in `System.Net` namespace).

Another advice, you can use a Console Application to start testing the above mentioned classes, which makes debugging and the job easier at the beginning.

If you are considering using multithreading, do it asynchronously to take advantage of the APM.